# How to make the BufferedReader write to a file using the text inside of a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, gettext, bufferedwriter

I have a project involving a recipe book that saves info like ingredients, utilities, etc. and i need to make the fields that those details are entered in, save that text to a file. Each field is a JTextField. The only thing being saved is text to a .txt.
*the class is called recipereader, but i am only writing to the file*ignore the name* If i could get a response that showed what the code would look like that would be much appreciated. Also, i am using bufferedwriter so id like to keep within that unless its not possible.

```
PrintWriter outputStream=new PrintWriter("recipe001.txt");
outputStream.println(recipeName.getText());
outputStream.close();
```

recipeName is the JTextField.(and i know the code is wrong). i would like the content of each `JTextField`to be presented with one line, so thats why im doing `println.` Its quite simple but i do not know how to do the `getText` from the `JTextField` My frame is in another class from this code here

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in general correct and would work. [JTextField.getText()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getText%28%29) (inherited method) will return the text for you.

When reading JavaDoc, also aways check that you inherit from the parent class. This may be exactly the functionality you would need.

Comment: yea i think maybe its a problem with how my class is, is this right?  public class RecipeReader {
 public(JTextField[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{